# How to keep two auth system in django

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication

I am working on product where my client can list products on the websites using my platform.
I already have login system for my clients.
Now I want to have another auth service for buyers on website that is client of out clients.
I cant keep both the users in same django table.
How to aproch this problem?

Comment: Generally, this is not possible or at least going to give more trouble than expected. Isn't a 1to1 relation with models specific for buyers and clients the solution for you? So both can have it's own fields, but you keep the "regular" Django authentication. See https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone

Comment: why not user role-based authentication system?

Comment: Django is very matured for: 
-Groups
-Permissions 

You can actually create different roles and categorise users (e.g. Buyers, Customer, Support as Groups)

Comment: Thanks @Sopan as per my reaserch till now that is the conclusion but I want to make sure that I am not missing anything.
I was trying to do it with RemoteUserMiddleware, Is it possible to do it that way?

Comment: Thanks @sky_1 yes that could be one of the solution. I want to explore if it can be done with separate table of service itself. I was trying to do it with RemoteUserMiddleware, Is it possible to do it that way?

Comment: RemoteUserMiddleware makes use of something called `REMOTE_USER`. It's kind delegation of authentication to Web Server. That's not useful for you unless you want to delegate authentication to Web Server from Django Based Web Application. 

Your requirement is different - it's not the authentication, its related to roles and permissions. May be you are thinking of creating different tables for users - but still it's not related to authentication.